# Method to draw a line

Tags: c#, windows

My Professor gave us this question

> Write a method called Drawline that accepts as input an integer n and generates a line of output in lstOutput with n hyphens.  That is, if n = 5 we have a line of ‘-----‘ displayed in the list box.

Basically he wants me to type a number in a text box and when i click the button it should display that many hyphens in a list box. Using visual Studio C# WindowsFormApp.

Here's my code:

```
private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double n;
    Drawline(out n);
}

private void Drawline(out double n)
{
    n = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    string strline = "";
    for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++);
    strline += '-';
    lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(strline, n));
}
```

It works but no matter what number i put in the text box only one hyphen shows up. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++);` Note the semi-colon.

Comment: Also, `String.Format` doesn't seem needed here.

Comment: What's the use of `out n` here? Your `Drawline()` method should return a string that is then added to a ListBox in the `btn3_Click` handler. You can just return `new string('-', n);` and of course you should use `int.TryParse()`, not `double.Parse()`, but in `btn3_Click` (your `Drawline` method should know nothing about `textBox1` and `lstOutput`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `for` loop in `DrawLine` method.

You need to remove the semi-colon at the end of the `for` statement, so the `strLine += '-';` will belong to the loop, not just be executed once.

```
private void Drawline(out double n)
{
    n = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    string strline = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        strline += '-';
    lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(strline, n));
}
```

Comment: this helped but, it gives me 5 hyphens no matter what number i put in. i dont know if my numbers are messed up or what. any idea for that? sorry this is my first C# class and this is new stuff to me

Comment: I misread your code, I have just fixed it. You need a temporary variable to act as a counter.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may be making this more complicated than it has to be.

It is unclear “why” the `DrawLine` method returns a double value using the `out` property? Is this a requirement? If it is not a requirement, then it is unnecessary.

Also, as per the requirement… *”Write a method called Drawline that accepts as input an integer n”* … if this is the requirement, I have to ask why is the method accepting a `double` value? This would not fit with the requirement.

Below is a simplified version and should fit your requirements. First in the button click event, we want to get the `integer` value from the text box. We need to assume the user typed in a value that is NOT a valid integer. If the value is NOT a valid integer greater than zero (0), then we will display a message box indicating such.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if ((int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int value)) && value > 0) {
    Drawline(value);
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("String is not a number or is less than 1 : " + textBox1.Text);
  }
}
```

Next the `DrawLine` method that simply adds a string of “-“ character(s) to the list box. Note the passed-in/accepted value of `n` has already been verified as a valid integer number greater than 0.

```
private void Drawline(int n) {
  lstOutput.Items.Add(new string('-', n));
}
```

If you MUST use a `for` loop to generate the string, it may look something like…

```
private void Drawline(int n) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sb.Append("-");
  }
  lstOutput.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```